# HttpPostedFileBase always returns null and image does not get posted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I seem to be having a problem when posting images.I have checked many questions on stackoverflow and on other forums that discuss this topic but none seem to provide the answer I need.Here is my code:

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductManager", FormMethod.Post, new{enctype = "multipart/form-data"})){

    <ul>
        ....
        <li>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductImagePath , "Avatar")
             <input type="file" id="ProductAvatar" name="ProductAvatar" />
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductImagePath , new { id = "AvatarHiddenField"})
        </li>
         <li>
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName , "Product Name")
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
         </li>
         .....
    </ul>
}
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create( FormCollection collection ,  HttpPostedFileBase avatar)
        {
            string file = collection["ProductAvatar"];
            var avatars = avatar;
        }
```

From debugging I found that HttpPostedFileBase returns null.The other form data in the collection gets posted succesfully.Only the image does not get posted.I can not seem to acces ProductAvatar from either the FormCollection or the HttpPostedFileBase , it seems like it's not even posted

How can I corect this problem?

Comment: Please, stop posting duplicate questions, you can edit your original one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use change the name of your `HttpPostedFile` parameter to the same name of your input file on the form, or you also can use `Request.Files` and get by the by the `name` attribute of your input file, try something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ProductAvatar"];

   if (file.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      file.SaveAs(/* path */);
   }

   // othyer tasks

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `name` attribute is what the browser will send on a post/get form when submit.

Answer (score 6):

Your action method parameter name needs to match the file input name.

So with this:

```
<input type="file" id="ProductAvatar" name="ProductAvatar" />
```

You'll need a method signature like:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase productAvatar)
```

Comment: +1 I'd highly recommend this.  Take advantage of MVC as much as possible.  I avoid using `Request` or anything in `HttpContext` passed from the browser directly as much as possible.